# Converting complexObjectArray to a Usable Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a script which has output which looks like the following:

[image]

Which is something I've not experienced before. Normally the result would be the array and then the `stdClass Object` which I convert to an array using `(array) $result`. This one seems to be nested an extra 2 times however, so I have no idea how to access it so that I can turn each of those objects into an array.

So what I need to be able to achieve, for example, is that if I use the code `echo $orders[0]->customer_id`, the result would be `716`'.

Could anybody please advise? My code is below if required. Thank you very much.

```
<?php
    $client= new SoapClient('*Magento URL*');
    $session_id = $client->login((object)array('username' => '*Magento Username*', 'apiKey' => '*Magento Password*'));

    try {
        $result = $client->salesOrderList((object)array('sessionId' => $session_id->result, 'filters' => null)); 
        $orders = (array) $result;

        echo '<pre>', print_r($orders), '</pre>';

    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage(), '<hr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I receive `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7` when I use this. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `$orders = $result->result->complexObjectArray;`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Please put as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` is an object with a `result` property which is an object with a `complexObjectArray` property that is an integer indexed array of objects. So:

```
$orders = $result->result->complexObjectArray;
```

Then:

```
echo $orders[0]->customer_id;
```

If there is more than one item in the array then you would need to loop over it.  If there is only ever one then include the `0` when defining `$orders`:

```
$orders = $result->result->complexObjectArray[0];
```

Then:

```
echo $orders->customer_id;
```